# I have some erroes with sync gradle in android studio version 3.1.1

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.1

I installed android studio version 3.1.1 and when android studio start to sync with gradle i get some errors and errors are:

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1.
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1.
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1.
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1.
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>
> Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1
>   Show in File
>   Show in Project Structure dialog

and my build.gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hadi.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

please help me to solve errors.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. On topic and how to ask apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

replace`com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1` with `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+'`